# What are these pipes

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I have 2 4 inch PVC pipes sticking up about 3 inches above ground in my flower bed, one is capped the other isn't. I ran over the capped one with the lawn mower and every time a toilet was flushed I could hear it from that pipe, I replaced that cap as it was threaded and an easy fix. My question is what are these and should both be capped? I have city sewage.

Comment: How far apart are they? What jurisdiction do you live in? Perhaps [this](http://www.homeownersnetwork.com/booktopic/drain-sewer-pipe-cleanouts/) may help.

Answer (score 2):

The caped pipe you could hear the toilet flush is the clean out . This the location a snake is put in if the pipes backup. Is the second pipe outside a bathroom or kitchen? If so it may be a second clean out especially if they are quite a distance apart and if it is a clean out it should be capped also. A second possibility for the uncapped pipe is a clean out for the drains to the storm water runoff from your gutters these don't require a cap but it is a good idea so material from the flower bed dosent fill it up.